# FBPXL Elite Series X-Large Boom Pole

Tags: untagged

Hi

I am wondering if any of you SSD's have ever used the FBPXL Elite Series X-Large Boom Pole from PSC. I am a vDB man myself as well as a Panamic so maybe you might be able to give me a comparative analysis based on experience. There are some very good boompoles out there and some questionable ones.

Looking forward to your resposes.

Thanks.

Chris

Answer (score 1):

hi,

I've boomed with all brands mentoined, but not with a large PSC boom. I've used a very small one, very light and fits in a medium sized pelican (which is handy on airplanes). That pole was kind of sensitive to handling noise, unless you're a veteran (which I am certainly not), because there's no foam/soft grip on the pole. Panamic does have that and works great as a large boom pole in my opinion.

Couldn't you rent the PSC to check it out?

Greetings,
Arnoud